# How to add a Gutenberg block and generate a custom CSS file with ACF Pro

Tags: php, css, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress-gutenberg, auto-generate

Up front I apologies for my bad grammer (I am trying to the best I can).

We are building a custom template for WordPress with Gutenberg blocks in combination with ACF Pro. Every ACF Pro Gutenberg block has its advanced tab where you can edit font sizes, colors, weight, height, width, background colors, etc. But I was wondering. Is it possible to generate a CSS file when you add an ACF Pro Gutenberg block specifically for that block, just as Elementor is doing with their style sheets.
In Elementor you add modules to the page but every module you add has a custom Class and ID assigned to that specific module. This Class and ID are added to a .css file.

How am I able to do this with WordPress and ACF Pro?

Sorry, I do not have any code examples because I was wondering if this is even possible in the correct way.

Comment: this basically has nothing to do with ACF.

I mean sure, you could generate CSS JIT style...however I would discourage from this in most cases.
If you got simple changes, just add them inline as a style attribute. There is nothing wrong with that. (adding ALL your CSS like that, would be wrong however)

Comment: @Frizzant So there is no way I can auto generate a CSS file with ACF values specifically for a certain block when I add a block to Gutenberg or make any changes?

Comment: Sure there is. It's just not very easy. Can't really guide you on that.
Are they entirely random, or could you cover the use cases with a reasonable ammount of CSS? Then you could use block-styles for example?